# Multiple line replace jQuery textarea

Tags: jquery

I have a question with the following script, apparently works well when a line of code, but if to replace several lines of code does not work :(

**A line of code:**

[image]

**Multiple lines of code**

[image]

**When the result should be:**

```
http://www.domain.com/myimages/123/123_small.jpg
http://www.domain.com/myimages/456/456_small.jpg
http://www.domain.com/myimages/789/789_small.jpg
```

**JSFIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/mxk6fLpg/

```
<h3>Enter:</h3>

<textarea value="" id="enter"></textarea>
<h3>Result:</h3>

<textarea class="disable" id="result"></textarea><br />
<input type="reset" value="Resetear" class="button reset" />
```

```js
$('#enter').keyup(function () {
    var url = 'http://www.domain.com/myimages/' + $(this).val() + '/' + $(this).val() + '_small.jpg';
    var result = url;
    $('#result').html(result);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be better way to implement this but, you can split your string with line breaks and display each line break strings in new line. To accomplish this, here is your modified code:

```
$('#enter').keyup(function () {
    var eachLine = $(this).val().split('\n');
    var result = '';       
    for(var i=0;i<eachLine.length;i++){
        var url = 'http://www.domain.com/myimages/' + eachLine[i] + '/' + eachLine[i] + '_small.jpg';
        result = result + url + '\n';
    }        
    $('#result').html(result);
});
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mxk6fLpg/2/

Comment: right, i updated the jsfiddle and the code. check it out again please. It was caused because when declared the `result` variable, I did not define its type. It is updated now.

Comment: Muchas gracias, usted es un gran tipo :)